# java: read vs readNBytes of the InputStream instance

Tags: java, io, inputstream

In java, `InputStream` class has methods `read(byte[], int, int)` and `readNBytes(byte[], int, int)`. It seems that these two methods have exactly the same functionality, so I wonder what are the differences between them.

Comment: What answer do you expect beyond a copy and paste from the respective Javadocs?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I just want to know the differences between them, is there any subtle differences about functionality or implementation or anything? Their javadocs are so alike and I cannot figure out the difference.

Comment: What part of the Javadoc didn't you understand? The difference is perfectly clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Edited for better visibility of discussion in the comments:*

- `read()` says it attempts to read *"up to `len` bytes ... **but a smaller number may be read**. This method blocks until input data is available, end of file is detected, or an exception is thrown."*
- `readNBytes()` says *"blocks until `len` bytes of input data have been read, end of stream is detected, or an exception is thrown."*

Even though the *JDK's implementation* for `InputStream` is likely to give you identical results for both methods, the documented differences mean than other classes inheriting from it may behave differently.

E.g. Given the stream `'12345<end>'`, `read(s,0,10)` is allowed to return `'123'`, whereas `readNbytes()` is more likely to keep going to look for an end-of-stream and give you the whole thing.

---

*Original answer:*

You're right that the javadocs are very similar. When in doubt, always drop down to the source. Most IDEs make it easy to attach the OpenJDK source and lets you drill down to them.

This is `readNBytes` from [InputStream.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/jdk10/jdk/file/777356696811/src/java.base/share/classes/java/io/InputStream.java):

```
public int readNBytes(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
    Objects.requireNonNull(b);
    if (off < 0 || len < 0 || len > b.length - off)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    int n = 0;
    while (n < len) {
        int count = read(b, off + n, len - n);
        if (count < 0)
            break;
        n += count;
    }
    return n;
}
```

As you can see, it actually performs a call to `read(byte[],int,int)`. The difference in this case is that if the actual read bytes is less than your specified `len`, **it will attempt to read() again** until it is confirmed that there is actually nothing left to be read.

Edit: Note that

1. This is *OpenJDK*'s implementation of the base `InputStream`. Others may differ.
2. Subclasses of `InputStream` may also have their own overridden implementation. Consult the doc/source for the relevant class.

Comment: Right you are! But I wonder in which cases the results carried out by these two methods will be different.

Comment: Seems that the javadoc for `read()` just says it attempts to read up to `len` bytes, whereas `readNBytes()` actually says up to `len` bytes *or end-of-stream is reached*. Though in the source we can see that both behave very similarly, the way the doc is worded means that it allows overrides of `read()` to just give you whatever it can as long as it's less than `len` bytes. Even if there's an EOS within range, it might stop beforehand.

Comment: Great insight! I have never thought that `read() ` method can be overridden, in which situation `readNBytes()` does differ. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The Javadoc for `readNBytes()` does *not* say 'reads up to `len` bytes'. It says 'Reads the requested number of bytes from the input stream into the given byte array', and goes on to make it clear that exactly `len` bytes are read unless end of stream intervenes. Furthermore the two methods do not 'behave very similarly'.

Comment: @user207421 Fair point. I'm almost certain the short description at the time did say the above. I'll update, thank you. That said, if you look  at the OpenJDK source, `readNBytes(,,)` calls `read(,,)`, which calls `read()`; and the doc for `read()` says *"..blocks until input data is available, the end of the stream is detected, or an exception is thrown"*. Which causes the default implementations to behave very similarly if `read()` actually does what it should do.

Comment: It calls `read()` *in a loop* whose purpose is to *ensure* that it reads `len` bytes and no fewer unless end of tream intervenes. There is no 'very similarly' about it.

Comment: It calls `read(,,)` in a loop. And in turn, `read(,,)` calls `read()` in a loop. The doc for `read()` says: "blocks until input data is available, the end of the stream is detected, or an exception is thrown".  So if the implementation for `read()` follows its documented behaviour, you'd reach EOS with `read(,,)` too.

Comment: Of course you would reach EOS, but if you didn't, `readNBytes()` would read `len` bytes where `read()` need not.

Comment: It need not, but it will *in the OpenJDK implementation*, because of the nature of `read(void)`. Hence the similarities, unless overridden.

Answer (score -1):

**Difference: len only 【expects】 to read in the number of bytes, while read(byte[] b, int off, int len) may continue to execute subsequent code even if it does not read full len, while readNBytes (byte[] b, int off, int len) ensure that subsequent code is not executed if it does not read full len**

ByteArrayInputStream.read(byte [] b, int off, int len) is implemented as:

```
public synchronized int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) {
  Objects.checkFromIndexSize(off, len, b.length);
  if (this.pos >= this.count) {
     return -1;
  } else {
     int avail = this.count - this.pos;
     if (len > avail) {
        len = avail;
     }

     if (len <= 0) {
        return 0;
     } else {
        System.arraycopy(this.buf, this.pos, b, off, len);
        this.pos += len;
        return len;
     }
  }
```

}

It can be seen that when len>available, len is truncated to available, and the actual number of bytes read subsequently=available, while available represents the estimated value of the number of bytes that can still be read in the current stream. There is a possibility that after executing int available=this. count - this. pos; After calculating the availability in this code, due to new data entering ByteArrayInputStream, this. count was increased by other threads. For example, there were originally 10 bytes in the input stream that were not read, but we wanted to get 20 bytes, so we called read (s, 0,20) l, and in the read function, available=this. count - this. pos; After execution, the available is 10, but at this point, another thread added 100 bytes to the stream. Therefore, even though the expected 20 bytes could be read, only 10 were read.

Let's take a look at the implementation of InputStream. readNBytes (byte [] b, int off, int len):

```
public int readNBytes(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
  Objects.checkFromIndexSize(off, len, b.length);

  int n;
  int count;
  for(n = 0; n < len; n += count) {
     count = this.read(b, off + n, len - n);
     if (count < 0) {
        break;
     }
  }

  return n;
```

}

The for loop here is the difference between read and readNbytes. ReadNbytes does not compromise (len=available), but instead stays in the function through the for loop when there is not enough data to read and does not continue to execute. Using the previous example, len=20, and currently there are only 10 bytes in the stream, the first round of the loop did not read enough 20 bytes, but it will continue to loop to ensure that 20 bytes are read when exiting the readNBytes function